# Show that the ring $\mathbb C[x^3,x^2y,xy^2,y^3]$ is normal, but it is not a unique factorisation domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

OExercise I am trying to solve:

> Show that the ring $R = \mathbb{C}[x^{3}, x^{2}y, xy^{2}, y^{3}]$ is normal, but $R$ is not a unique factorisation domain.

Normal means that $R$ is integrally closed in its field of fractions, i.e.,
$$R= \{ s \in \text{Frac}(R):s \text{ is integral over }R\},$$ where the field of fractions $\mathrm{Frac}(R)=\{\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}:f,g \in R \text{ s.t. } g\neq0\}$ and $s$ is integral over $R$ if there is a monic $h(t)\in (\mathbb{C}[x^{3}, x^{2}y, xy^{2}, y^{3}])[t]$ s.t. $h(t)=0$.

I know how to show it is not a UFD: $x^{3}y^{3}=(x^{3})(y^{3})=(x^{2}y)(xy^{2})$.

I have tried showing that any $h(x,y) \in \mathrm{Frac}(R)$ which is integral is actually in $R$, but I am not getting anywhere with it because all the ways I know to show a ring is normal use the fact that $R$ is a UFD.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: That equality does not prove that $R$ is not a UFD. In $\mathbb Z$ we also have $2\cdot 6=3\cdot 4$. You need to show that those factors are irreducible.

Comment: In order to show that $R$ is integrally closed I suggest you to take a look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1577054/121097).

Comment: @user26857 Thanks! That question cleared things up, I couldn't find it when searching as I was looking for the key word normal not just integrally closed. Your point about showing those factors are irreducible: does it not follow directly from the fact that they are adjoined to the ring '$\mathbb{C}$'? I guess my question is: How would I show they're irreducible other than saying it is obvious?

Comment: Look at the possible decompositions of $x^3$ in the polynomial ring $k[x,y]$ and notice that lower powers of $x$ don't belong to $R$.